# Why don't we have a help for Bitcoin Core CLI options in the same way as we do for CLI commands?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli

There is detailed help for bitcoin-cli commands using for example:

`./src/bitcoin-cli getconnectioncount help`.

However, there isn't generally detailed help for bitcoin-cli options such as

`./src/bitcoin-cli -netinfo help`.

(Note the dash in front of `netinfo` with no such dash before `getconnectioncount`)

Is there a reason why there isn't the same help for bitcoin-cli options?

Jon Atack added on IRC:

> If not is there an already planned way to add to the help doc and
> would this be a good idea? For more detailed help than in
> `./src/bitcoin-cli -h`
>
> I was thinking it might be good to have a detailed help doc for
> `-netinfo` either with `help -netinfo` or expand the existing one at
> `./src/bitcoin-cli -h | grep -A3 netinfo` or add a `doc/netinfo.md`
> file

Comment: I don't understand why you dump random conversations between developers on this site. Without context this question makes no sense - most CLI options do have help.

Answer (score -2):

This simply is a shortcoming that should be fixed.

David Harding added on IRC:

> `help <command>` is for RPCs; `-h` is for a quick summary of CLI
> parameters.  Extended CLI parameter help should probably be in a
> manual page.

Comment: That's pretty much the opposite of the truth. The `bitcoin-cli` options in question (`-netinfo`), (`-getinfo`), (`-generate`) are as much end user features as the RPC commands, they've just been moved from bitcoind to bitcoin-cli. The fact that they aren't listed in -help or through other means is a shortcoming that should just be fixed.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Will update.